# Using an authentication token obtained from v1 API in a V2 API request

Tags: box-api

As I couldn't find how to authenticate with the V2 API with my Box credential I tried to use the authentication token from a V1 API with a V2 request.

I discovered something weird and I'd like to know if something is wrong.

The documentation of the header to authenticate a V2 request described it like this for a curl command):
curl -k -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/5053864602/content -H "Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN"

With curl I couldn't get anything, not even an error message.
However I tried this request with Postman and in the response I could see that the token was invalid.

In this forum I found that the header could have a different form including the **api_key** so I tried the following:
curl -k -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/5053864602/content -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"

and this request works as I could get the content of the file like with a V1 API call.

Could someone from BOX explains what's going on? I suspect that I'm not the only one having this problem...

Comment: I can see API documentation is changed. 4-5 days back `Authorization` header contained both authToken and APIkey. May be a technical change from BOX. Have to wait for BOX developers for some reply.

Answer (score 1):

The Box API now supports OAuth 2, which has a completely revised authentication flow. You can find the instructions on how to use OAuth 2.0 with Box here: http://developers.box.com/oauth/

V1-style auth is still also supported in the V2 API, though it will eventually be deprecated. However, **if you're starting to build against the Box API now, you should use OAuth 2** in order to avoid having to do double work and port over in the future.

There are several differences between V1-style auth and OAuth 2.0, but notably in OAuth 2.0 you don't have to sign API requests with your API key (which is now called a 'client id' with OAuth 2.0), only the access_token you get through the auth process.

You can read more about our implementation of OAuth 2 in my previous link, and also about the spec in general [here](http://oauth.net/2/).

Comment: Sean, are you saying that we are now required to implement OAuth2 if we want to use the V2 API, or it is now an option?

Comment: Both V1 auth and OAuth 2 will work with the V2 API for now, though we are planning to sunset V1 Auth support in the V2 API eventually (no sooner than several months from now). When the V1 API is fully deprecated in ~a year, V1 style auth will also be deprecated along with it. OAuth 2 is much more secure and standardized, so we're obviously encouraging people to adopt it as soon as they can.

Comment: I asked because requests that were working fine are now reporting "wrong auth token" without any change in my code and for newly authenticated users.

Comment: Hm, that is strange. We haven't heard of this happening with anyone else so far. Some of our official clients like our iOS app are using V1 auth and have not experienced anything like this. If you're still running into this issue it might be worthwhile here to post with what you're running into so that we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I was having (what seems to be) a similar problem.  Replacing 'boxauth' with the 'bearer' or 'boxapi' Authorization headers would result in a 400: 'malformed_auth_header' for both standard and shared_link requests.

Comment: Yeah, you can't just use an old v1 Auth-token as a bearer-token.  They're not interchangeable in our system.  If you use a v1 auth-token, you'll have to continue to pass it in as an auth-token and also include the api-key in your request.